# Memory-efficient utility to return N first sorted values

Tags: pipe, sort, xargs, parallelism, coreutils

I would like to implement a very popular MapReduce example using only existing programs operating in a UNIX way. The problem is to find N most frequent values in an enormous amount of data. The generic solution on any general-purpose programming language is:

1. Map each value from the list to a tuple (value, 1).
2. Group same values summing up their counts.
3. Sort values by counts keeping top N frequent items.

For efficiency each step should fit into memory and be parallelized if possible. Thus I can use `split`, `paste`, `xargs` and `sort` from "core utils" and `parallel` from "more utils" for the first two steps still satisfying problem constraints. But in order to implement the last step I need always keep not more than N values simultaneously or else I will quickly run out of memory, so obviously I cannot use `sort` piped to `head`. A common approach is to use "priority queue" data structure, but is there a program for that?

Comment: The actual problem you want to solve is `sort|uniq -c|sort -n|head -n $N` - only in a more efficient way, right? Can you give some (small) example input and the expected output?

Comment: Imagine a very long list of any text words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU sort would benefit from a --range function to support this common operation:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2009-07/msg00019.html

So I'd suggest to implement that in a local version of sort(1),
and we'll merge it upstream too to make it generally available